# How to set Tab divider in custom Tab Widget in android

Tags: android, tabwidget

How to set custom or default tab divider in tab widget. I have tried below code to create custom tab widget.

```
private void setTabs()
{
    TabHost tabhost=getTabHost();

    tabhost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(TabWidget.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);//here Application crashes

    tabhost.addTab(createTab(FoodTabGroup.class, "foods", "Foods", R.drawable.tab_foods));
    tabhost.addTab(createTab(BeveragesTabGroup.class, "beverages", "Beverages", R.drawable.tab_beverages));
    tabhost.addTab(createTab(DessertsTabGroup.class, "desserts", "Desserts", R.drawable.tab_desserts));
    tabhost.addTab(createTab(WinesTabGroup.class, "wines", "Wines", R.drawable.tab_wines));
    tabhost.addTab(createTab(OrderTabGroup.class, "order", "Order", R.drawable.tab_order));

    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 140;
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().width = 140;
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().width = 140;
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().width = 140;
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().width = 140;

    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height= 150;
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height= 150;
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height= 150;
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height= 150;
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height= 150;

    tabhost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

private TabSpec createTab(final Class<?> intentClass, final String tag, 
        final String title, final int drawable)
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, intentClass);

    final View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getTabHost().getContext()).
        inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
    TextView txtTab=(TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
    txtTab.setText(title);
    txtTab.setPadding(8, 9, 8, 9);
    txtTab.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    txtTab.setTextSize(18);

    ImageView imgTab=(ImageView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
    imgTab.getLayoutParams().height=80;
    imgTab.getLayoutParams().width=80;
    imgTab.setImageResource(drawable);

    return getTabHost().newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tab).setContent(intent);
}
```

Please help me for setting custom divider in tab widget..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version are you trying to run on?

setDividerDrawable() takes the id of the drawable you want to use for your dividers. The argument you are passing is actually used in conjunction with setShowDividers(), which tells it where to draw the dividers.

Replace...

```
tabhost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(TabWidget.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
```

with...

```
tabhost.getTabWidget().setShowDividers(TabWidget.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
tabhost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable( ... ); //id of your drawble resource here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
```